# If/else within a grep statement

Tags: grep, json

I am trying to find all instances of `"type":"FollowEvent"`, and then within those instances, if the string `"actor":` is not followed by `{`, then capture the string enclosed in `"` that comes immediately after `"actor":`. Else, capture the string enclosed in `"` that comes immediately after `"login:"`.

What I have so far:

```
zgrep -e '"type":"FollowEvent"' /path/to/dir/* | zgrep -o '"actor":(?!{)*' | cut -f2- -d: | cut -d',' -f1 > results_file.txt
```

EDIT:
What this `zgrep` does:

For all files in /path/to/dir, for all lines that contain `"type":"FollowEvent"`, find `"actor:"` not followed by `{`. Then take everything after the `:`, and before the next `,`. Put the results in `results_file.txt`.

EDIT SHOWING DATA:

A single line in the files that are being grep'd could look like this:

```
{"repo":{"url":"https://url","name":"/"},"type":"FollowEvent","public":true,"created_at":"2011-05-29","payload":{"target":{"gravatar_id":"73","id":64,"repos":35,"followers":58,"login":"username3"}},"actor":{"gravatar_id":"06","id":439,"url":"https://url","avatar_url":"https://.png","login":"username4"},"id":"14"}
```

or like this:

```
{"repo":{"url":"https://url/","name":"/"},"type":"FollowEvent","public":true,"created_at":"2011-04-01","payload":{"target":{"gravatar_id":"40","repos":2,"followers":1,"login":"username2"},"actor":"username1","actor_gravatar":"de4"},"actor":{"gravatar_id":"de4","id":716,"url":"https://url","avatar_url":"https://.png","login":"username2"},"id":"12"}
```

Comment: As this looks like JSON format why do not use `jq`?

Comment: Why the downvote? Also, if jq is a solution, could you please show me?

Comment: Post a sample JSON snippet containing the instance and show us how would you like to parse it

Comment: I find it difficult to follow your `grep`s.  What is the actual _data_ that you'd like to extract from this JSON document?  Is it the `target.login` bit?

Comment: Thank you @Inian, I've edited to explain further.

Comment: Thank you @Kusalananda, I've edited to explain further.

Answer (score 2):

The username listed as `login` under `target` can be had from both JSON documents using `jq`:

```
$ jq -r '.payload.target.login' file1.json
username3
```

Likewise, the `login` under `actor` can be had:

```
$ jq -r '.actor.login' file1.json
username4
```

If you want to make the output conditional on the `type` (and not produce anything if the `type` is not `FollowEvent`):

```
jq -r 'select(.type == "FollowEvent") | .actor.login' file1.json
```

Comment: I cannot use `jq`, because I cannot install it. I'm working with Python 2.7, which I suspect is part of the issue.

Comment: @StatsSorceress `jq` has no dependency on Python.  You could easily use a JSON parser in Python if you wished to do that instead.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda, but I can't install `jq`. Is there a way to do if/else within `grep`?